# Derivative vs division

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a function $s=16t^2$ now if we find $\frac{ds}{dt}$ we get $v=28t$ but when we simply divide we know $s/t=v$ so $s/t=16t$. Why classical division fails?

Comment: $\frac d{dt} 16\,t^2\neq 28t$.  More to the point, the formula distance = rate $\times$ time applies to constant speed.

Comment: Rather than "*why does it fail*", a better question is *why did you think it would work that way in the first place*?

Comment: We would really appreciate if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format maths. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even though $\frac{ds}{dt}$ looks like a fraction, it **is not** one. Explicitly, it means
$$\frac {ds}{dt} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {s(t+h)-s(t)}{h}$$
and this is what a derivative is. Doing this out for $s (t)=16t^2$ provides

$$\begin {align*}
\frac {ds}{dt} &=& \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {s(t+h)-s(t)}{h} \\
&=&  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {16 (t+h)^2-16t^2}{h} \\
&=&  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {32th+16h^2}{h} \\
&=&  \lim_{h\to 0} 32t+16h \\
&=& 32t.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

s=16t^2.
but,dv/dt=32t

But,the velocity is the rate of change of displacement
it means that is their having something is displacement &we take the difference between initial and final velocity and then divide by time

Comment: We would really appreciate if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format maths. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to define what a derivative is.

A derivative is a function that gives us the rate in change odd another function at any given time,. The rate of change is often referred to as the slope of the line.

That settled.

In order to calculate the slope of a function at a given point without use derivatives, is complicated unless the function of a straight line, in which case we use: m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1).

For other functions, we know that the slope is not constant, so we need to use something a little bit more complicated,  than the previous function: m = (f (dx + x1) - f (x1)) / ( dx + x - x).

Where m will give us the slope of the line at x when dx is equal to zero.

The above function when expanded and simplified using algebra and division gives us the slope of the line at x.

(This is how we prove that we can take a derivative).

Admittedly this is not an answer to your question? Howdy I think it is an answer to what you were really asking.

Comment: We would really appreciate if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format maths. Thanks.